# JFrame; starts by displaying array element [1] from for loop, rather than [0]

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, jframe, jlabel

I have drafted the below application, to loop through an array of Strings (I am a beginner). The aim is to display the numbers one through five on a JFrame, using JLabel; changing each second.

When the JFrame pops up on screen, it curiously displays the number "two" which is at array position one. This is contrary to my expectation and I cannot figure out why.

i is initiated to 1; which is stored in "temp"; which is then added to the JLabel and consequently the JFrame. Is there a delay in using this methodology; i.e by the time the JLabel has updated; the for loop has already advanced? Or, I understand Java.swing has an issue with threads...?

Your help would be much appreciated.

J

```
package testApplication;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Count {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        String[] numbers = {"one","two","three","four","five"};
        JLabel numToDisplay = new JLabel("");
        String temp;

        //Initiate JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Counting Application");
        frame.setSize(275,100);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++){
            temp = numbers[i];
            numToDisplay.setText(temp);
            frame.add(numToDisplay);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're blocking the event dispatching thread - use a Swing Timer instead

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Thread.sleep but rather use a Swing Timer so as not to put your GUI to sleep.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Count {
   private static int index = 0;

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      final String[] numbers = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
      final JLabel numToDisplay = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
      String temp;

      // Initiate JFrame
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Counting Application");
      frame.setSize(275, 100);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(numToDisplay);
      numToDisplay.setText(numbers[index]);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      int delay = 1000;
      new Timer(delay, new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            index++;
            if (index >= numbers.length) {
               ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            } else {
               numToDisplay.setText(numbers[index]);
            }
         }
      }).start();

   }
}
```

---

or

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Count2 extends JPanel {
   private static final String[] NUMBERS = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
   private static final int PREF_W = 300;
   private static final int PREF_H = 100;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
   private JLabel numToDisplay = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
   private int index = 0;

   public Count2() {
      numToDisplay.setFont(numToDisplay.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 60f));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      numToDisplay.setText(NUMBERS[index]);
      add(numToDisplay);
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      Dimension superSize = super.getPreferredSize();
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return superSize;
      }
      int w = Math.max(PREF_W, superSize.width);
      int h = Math.max(PREF_H, superSize.height);
      return new Dimension(w, h);
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         index++;
         if (index >= NUMBERS.length) {
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
         } else {
            numToDisplay.setText(NUMBERS[index]);
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Count2 mainPanel = new Count2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Count2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Might switch the add/setVisible statements, but it's possible setText will invalidate the container anyway

Comment: 1+, for using the Timer. But not sure the problem is  putting the GUI to sleep because the code is not executing on the Event Dispatch Thread. The code works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7 so it must be some kind Threading issue on other platforms. @jake, read up on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to better understand these comments.